# Page breaking at random - content disappearing

Tags: ee2

Here's a conundrum. A basic site, in EE2.4. This page has links in the left col, with content loading in the right col via a simple AJAX call. The code generate by EE is correct.

http://www.thresholdinteriorsnyc.com/press/

Some users report it working fine, while other report it broken. This doesn't seem to be browser-related. The problem of it not working is intermittent.

Hosted on on Rackspace.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the whole page blank or just the content area on the right?

Comment: Can you post more details about what seems to be broken? And, if it's just the content not appearing on the right, why do you suspect this is an EE issue and not a browser / Javascript issue?

Comment: On my ipad, on this page http://www.thresholdinteriorsnyc.com/press/ the latest ideabook links do not work. Id say javascript/jquery issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page content isn't loading/linking properly without www in the url. So http://www.thresholdinteriorsnyc.com/press/ works, but http://thresholdinteriorsnyc.com/press doesn't.

Check your htaccess for the proper redirects and watch out for absolute paths in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I believe the problem was a mismatch between www- and non-www URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Just browsing through the site, there are random javascript errors being triggered. I would start by attacking these one-by-one. Simply writing exceptions for the pages that don't need the functionality looks as thought it would help to begin. If you are triggering an error early on, a dependent function may randomly run or not run. This all depends on the browser, browser version, and how each handle the void variables being called.

As for anything else, it's hard to get a grip on it unless you could let us know what plug-ins, scripts you are using, and your template code to see how things are being handled.